# How to put the routes.json into web app from Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm developing a new site using Visual Studio, ASP.Net Core 3.1. The site will be set to use CI to deploy to Azure Web App.

I need a routes.json to adjust some behaviour. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/routes, this file need to be placed "at the root of app's build artifact folder".

How to do that in Visual Studio?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your concept of routing is wrong. The link you provide is a route to the front-end project. The front-end project is a static resource website, so the routes.json file can be used.

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Mar/13/Back-to-Basics-Rewriting-a-URL-in-ASPNET-Core

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @JasonPan Thanks. That's exactly what I'm using...

Comment: routes.json is used to [azure static web apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmoz8.png).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW6ME.png

Comment: @JasonPan Thanks for point it out. Seems web app still need to use the original way.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JasonPan. This question is based on a wrong concept.

routes.json is for a STATIC website only.